# stop button_tag type:submit from submitting an empty button parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I submit the following form, the get URI is displaying an empty button param...which doesn't hurt anything, but looks ugly.

How can I get rid of it?

Thanks

```
=simple_form_for :category,
  url: new_category_path,
  method: :get,
  class: "navbar-form navbar-left"  do |f|
  .input-group
    =f.search_field :search,
      type: "search",
      class: "form-control",
      placeholder: "Search for a category!"
    =f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => @category.id
    %span.input-group-btn
      =button_tag type:'submit', class: "btn btn-search" do
        %i.fa.fa-search
```

the url looks like:

`http://localhost:3000/categories/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&category%5Bsearch%5D=test&category%5Bparent_id%5D=1&button=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `:name` option to `nil`. That should do the trick.

```
%span.input-group-btn
  = button_tag type:'submit', class: "btn btn-search", name: nil do
    %i.fa.fa-search
```